# Can setInterval block user input?

Tags: javascript, react-native, time, react-hooks, setinterval

I tried to program a little stopwatch to test something out but after clicking "Start" and its running the "Stop", "Lap" and "Reset" Buttons register the input up to a second or more after I click them. What am I missing here?

My guess is it has something to do with the useEffect hook, but Im not sure since I haven't used React or React Native that extensively.

```
export default function TabOneScreen({ navigation }: RootTabScreenProps<'TabOne'>) {

    const [time, setTime] = useState<number>(0);
    const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);
    const [lapCounter, setLapCounter] = useState<number>(0);
    const [laps, setLaps] = useState<{count: number, lapTime: number}[]>([])

    useEffect(() => {
        var interval: any = null;
        if (timerOn) {
            interval = setInterval(() => {
                setTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 10);
            }, 10);
        } else if (!timerOn) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [timerOn]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>time:</Text>
                <View style={styles.timer}>
                    <Text>{("0" + Math.floor(time / 60000) % 60).slice(-2)}:</Text>
                    <Text>{("0" + Math.floor(time / 1000) % 60).slice(-2)}:</Text>
                    <Text>{("0" + (time / 10) % 100).slice(-2)}</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.buttons}>
                <Button
                    title="Start"
                    onPress={() => setTimerOn(true)}
                />
                <Button
                    title="Stop"
                    onPress={() => setTimerOn(false)}
                />
                <Button 
                    title="Lap"
                    onPress={() => {
                        setLapCounter(counter => counter += 1)
                        setLaps(prevLaps => [
                            ...prevLaps,
                            {count: lapCounter, lapTime: time}
                        ]
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <Button
                    title="Reset"
                    onPress={() => { 
                        setTimerOn(false)
                        setTime(0)
                        setLapCounter(0)
                        setLaps([])
                        }
                    }
                />
            </View>
            <FlatList
            data={laps}
                renderItem={({ item }) => 
                <View style={styles.lapList}>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>Lap: {item.count}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>{item.lapTime}</Text>
                </View>
                }   
            />

    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the "else if" you clear an empty interval (because you did not save the previous one anywhere). Create a new hook, such as `useTimer`.

Or use a premade like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-timer

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more what you mean by "saving the interval". Thanks for your response :)

Comment: The "setInterval" method returns a reference to the timer; you can cancel it in the future by passing that reference as an argument to "clearInterval()." So, you have two "clearInterval(interval)" statements. The latter is ok because the interval argument is set prior. But the first one in the "else if" block does nothing because the variable "interval" is empty. You can save the reference in a state, but my suggestion is if you can extract a custom hook, then do it or use a premade.